# #CGAL multi thread

Tags: multithreading, cgal

I would like to use cgal with multi-thread. I found on manual that I need intel TBB. I then installed intel TBB via synaptic package (sysatem: Ubuntu 12.04). 
How should I do for
1) recompile the library using TBB? (flags -DWITH_TBB=True seems not working)
2) Compile a generic file with TBB (I added on CMakeList.txt of my code the following lines:

find_package( TBB QUIET )
   if( TBB_FOUND )
     include(${TBB_USE_FILE})
     list(APPEND CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
   endif()

and cmake told: -- Found Intel TBB , but I'm not sure that after this is really linked)

3) Launching a program in multi-core (I do not think I should use mpirun stuff)

Thanks
Cesare

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to recompile the library. Only the 3D triangulations and 3D meshing packages are using TBB to have parallelism.

At the cmake level, one solution to make use of it is to have something like:

```
find_package( TBB QUIET )

if( TBB_FOUND )
  include(${TBB_USE_FILE})
  list(APPEND CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

right after `include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )`.

The choice of the using or not the parallelism is controlled by the `Parallel_tag` tag in the `TDS` like in [this](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/Triangulation_3_2parallel_insertion_in_delaunay_3_8cpp-example.html) and [that](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_implicit_sphere_8cpp-example.html) examples.

Comment: Yes but when I compiled the library TBB was not installed. Moreover, how can I specify to the library that TBB is installed (I suppose that at least part of it should be re-compiled, for instance: 3D meshing and 3D triangulation packages)? 
Also, I wrote my own code by using  Mesh_3/mesh_3D_image.cpp; Should I specify somewhere to use TBB?
Last: How can I run a CGAL multi-core program? I suppose that somewhere should I specify the number of core to use.

Thanks,

Cesare

Comment: Again, there is no need to recompile the library. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since CGAL is (nearly) a header-only library, there is no need to recompile (the multithreaded algorithms are in the headers).

Here is a simple example that computes a 3D Delaunay triangulation in parallel mode.

```
#define CGAL_LINKED_WITH_TBB

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/times.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<
            CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<K>,
            CGAL::Triangulation_cell_base_3<K>,
            CGAL::Parallel_tag
        > TDS;

typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K,TDS> Triangulation;
typedef Triangulation::Cell_handle            Cell_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle          Vertex_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Locate_type            Locate_type;
typedef Triangulation::Point                  Point;


void load_file(const char* filename, std::vector<Point>& points) {
    FILE* f = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(f == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file" << filename << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(!feof(f)) {
        double x,y,z;
        int nb_read = fscanf(f,"%lf %lf %lf", &x, &y, &z);
        if(nb_read == 3) {
            points.push_back(Point(x,y,z));
        }
    }
    std::cerr << "Loaded " << points.size() << " points" << std::endl;
    fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int num_grid_cells_per_axis=50;

    if(argc != 2 && argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " points_filename <num_grid_cells_per_axis>" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(argc == 3) {
        num_grid_cells_per_axis = atoi(argv[2]);
        std::cerr << "Using " << num_grid_cells_per_axis << " grid cells per axis" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<Point> pts;
    load_file(argv[1],pts);

    double xmin=1e30,ymin=1e30,zmin=1e30;
    double xmax=-1e30,ymax=-1e30,zmax=-1e30;
    for(size_t i=0; i<pts.size(); ++i) {
       xmin = std::min(xmin, pts[i].x());
       ymin = std::min(ymin, pts[i].y());
       zmin = std::min(zmin, pts[i].z());
       xmax = std::max(xmax, pts[i].x());
       ymax = std::max(ymax, pts[i].y());
       zmax = std::max(zmax, pts[i].z());
    }
    Triangulation::Lock_data_structure locks(
          CGAL::Bbox_3(xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax), 
          num_grid_cells_per_axis
    );



    std::cerr << "Computing triangulation" << std::endl;
    Triangulation T(pts.begin(), pts.end(), &locks);
    std::cerr << "Computed triangulation" << std::endl;

// Uncomment to save the result (note: takes a lot of time
// since it uses a std::map to map CGAL internal pointers to
// indices).   
//    std::ofstream oFileT("output",std::ios::out);
//    oFileT << T;

    return 0;
}
```

To compile it, I am using the following command line:

```
g++ -O3 CGAL_triangulate.cpp -lCGAL -lmpfr -lgmp -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -lpthread -o CGAL_triangulate
```

As an alternative, you may use the shellscript shipped with CGAL to create a CMakeFile:

```
cgal_create_CMakeLists -s executable
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents from `CGAL/TBB_support.cmake` to my `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
#TBB
find_package(TBB)

#copied from CGAL default cmake
if(TBB_FOUND AND NOT TARGET CGAL::TBB_support)
  message("here")
  if(NOT TARGET Threads::Threads)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
  endif()
  add_library(CGAL::TBB_support INTERFACE IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(CGAL::TBB_support PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "CGAL_LINKED_WITH_TBB;NOMINMAX"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "TBB::tbb;TBB::tbbmalloc;Threads::Threads")
endif()

# Add it as well
list(APPEND CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
```

Now include the `CGAL::TBB_support` with the executable you need to:

```
add_executable(cgal "../src/cgal.cpp")
target_link_libraries(cgal PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL CGAL::TBB_support)
```

then it works for me. Hope this helps.